# How to configure custom quick app in Quick Settings with GravityBox?

Tags: customization, xposed-framework, gravitybox

I am using Android Lollipop and my phone is rooted with the current version of Xposed framework and GravityBox is installed. I want to add an app shortcut with GravityBox, but can't do it. Here's the problem:

<sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

[image: IMG:]

Here is the screenshot of the GravityBox app:

<sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

[image: IMG:]

Now after adding the quick app shortcut I can't configure it.

Can anyone please help me with this? As I am on Lollipop I am bound to use third party apps to handle the situation.

Comment: Give us the screenshots of the GravityBox app where you customized the app shortcut

Comment: @Firelord I have uploaded the pic as per ur request.

Comment: Under Quick Settings Management  -> Tile specific Settings -> QuickApp tile  Settings: have you configured it already? If not, configure it, save it and may be restart as well if changes are not seen already.

Comment: @Firelord Thank you so much. It worked. Add it as an answer and I am going to accept it in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't configure the quick tile, but only enabled it. To configure it go to *QuickSettings management* → *Tile specific settings → QuickApp tile Settings*.

<sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

[image: IMG:]